# Combinatorics approach for player $A$ and $B$ rolling a 20-sided die

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, dice

Problem: *Consider players $A$ and $B$ rolling a 20-sided die. Player $B$ is allowed to re-roll. Assume that player $B$ will re-roll a single time if his first dice roll is $\leq 10$, and will not re roll if their first dice roll is $> 10$. The comparison is conducted between the last roll of $B$ (not the max roll of player $B$) with $A$. Let $RR$ and $NR$ denote the event of player $B$ rerolling and not rerolling. I want to find the probability of $NR$ occuring given that the first player rolls a higher number than the second player using a combinatorics approach.*

Denote $A$ and $B$ as the random variables for the outcome of $A$ and $B$'s tosses. First, I computed the case where player $B$ isn't allowed to reroll. The result of this case is used later. For this case where $B$ can't re-roll, consider the possibilities in which $A > B$ is satisfied:

For $B = 1$, there are 19 possibilities for $A$.

For $B = 2$, there are 18 possibilities for $A$.

...
For $B = 19$, there is 1 possibility for $A$.

So the number of possibilities for $A > B$ is $\frac{19 \cdot 20}{2} = 190$ when $B$ isn't allowed to re-roll. .

As stated previously in words, I want to find
$$
P(NR | A > B) 
$$

combinatorically. From a pure probability approach, I found that the probability is $\frac{9}{28}$ and confirmed this via monte carlo using 10 million trials.

At first, I sought the number of cases such that $A > B$. To do this, I considered the disjoint events $NR$ and $RR$. For the event $NR$, i.e., where player $B$ rolls once and his outcome is $> 10$, there are 45 cases where $A > B$. For $B = 11$, we have $9$ cases, ...., for $B = 19$, we have 1 case. So we have $\frac{9 \cdot 10}{2} = 45$ cases.

Then I considered the event $RR$, i.e., where player $B$ rolls a $\leq 10$ on the first toss and rolls again. This is effectively the same problem as the first problem I did in this post. Here, player $B's$ outcome can be $\in \{1, \ldots, 20\}$. As we saw at the beginning of this post, there are $190$ cases in which $A > B$.

So my first inclination was that
$$
P(NR | A > B) = \frac{45}{45 + 190} = \frac{45}{235}
$$

where the denominator is the sum of the number of $A > B$ cases in the two disjoint events $RR$ and $NR$.

But this probability is smaller than $\frac{9}{28}$, so it seems I may have overcounted or possibly undercounted somewhere.

It seems it is the the $RR$ case in which I overcounted the number of cases with $A > B$. In particularly, it seems that I may be duplicately counting the cases where $A > B \cap B \in \{11, \ldots, 19\}$, since I already counted this in the event $NR$. But it's not clear to me why this is overcounting when I defined $RR$ and $NR$ to be disjoint. Nevertheless, if we operate on this assumption that this did in fact overcount the cases where $B \in \{11, \ldots, 19\}$, then that means the number of cases where $A > B$ should be reduced by 45.

So now our result is

$$
P(NR | A > B) = \frac{45}{45 + 190} = \frac{45}{190}
$$

But this result is still not correct, and does not match the pure probability approach and monte carlo. Originally, I thought this problem would be simple from a combinatorics perspective, but now I am confused why my thought process doesn't work.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, you seem to change the rules in the middle of the problem.  And what does $\frac 9{10}=45$ mean?

Comment: @lulu That was a typo and should have been 9*10/2=45. The 45 represents the number of $A>B$ cases when $B$ doesn't re-roll. Where did I change the rules? Are you referringn to the start of "Now assume that player  will re-roll a single?" If so, then the text before that is for a related, but different problem.

Comment: Well...it's very confusing to state a "Problem" and then, while discussing that, change the terms around.  Why not start by stating the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: @lulu I reformatted the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will provide the way I would go about computing the desired probability without regard to the method of solution.  The key is to use Bayes' theorem:  $$\Pr[NR \mid A > B] = \frac{\Pr[A > B \mid NR]\Pr[NR]}{\Pr[A > B]}.$$  Given that no reroll occurred, the set of outcomes for $B$ is $\{11, 12, \ldots, 20\}$, each with probability $1/10$.  If $B = b$, then $\Pr[A > B \mid B = b] = \frac{20 - b}{20}$, hence $$\Pr[A > B \mid NR] = \sum_{b=11}^{20} \Pr[A > b]\Pr[B = b \mid NR] = \sum_{b=11}^{20} \frac{20 - b}{20}\cdot \frac{1}{10} = \frac{9}{40}.$$  The probability of the event $NR$ is simply $\Pr[B > 10] = \frac{1}{2}$.

The denominator, which is the marginal probability of $A > B$, is *not* $19/40$, which was the calculation when $B$ was not allowed to reroll.  By the law of total probability, $$\Pr[A > B] = \Pr[A > B \mid NR]\Pr[NR] + \Pr[A > B \mid RR]\Pr[RR].$$  The first term is the same as the numerator we calculated earlier.  For the second term, the probability $$\Pr[A > B \mid RR] = \sum_{b=1}^{20} \Pr[A > b]\Pr[B = b \mid RR] = \sum_{b=1}^{20} \frac{20 - b}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{20} = \frac{19}{40},$$ which *is* the original calculation--this is because if $B$ did reroll, then the outcomes and their probabilities are the same as if $B$ was never allowed to reroll in the first place.  But now we have to also take into account $\Pr[RR] = \frac{1}{2}$.  So our desired probability is $$\Pr[NR \mid A > B] = \frac{\frac{9}{40} \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{9}{40} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{19}{40} \cdot \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{9}{28}.$$

---

The problem with your approach is that your outcomes are not equiprobable, so you cannot simply add the number of outcomes as you did.  You have $45$ outcomes in which $A > B$ given $NR$, but these outcomes are out of a total conditional set of outcomes of size $20 \cdot 10 = 200$, whereas in the case that event $RR$ occurred, the total number of outcomes is $20 \cdot 20 = 400$.  Therefore, your calculation must be modified to weight the outcomes accordingly:  $$\frac{\frac{45}{200}}{\frac{45}{200} + \frac{190}{400}} = \frac{9}{28}.$$  In essence, you have intuitively applied Bayes' theorem in your reasoning but you applied it incorrectly.

---

To see how you would do this calculation if $\Pr[NR] \ne \Pr[RR]$, it is immediately obvious with Bayes' theorem.  But your "combinatorial" or enumerative approach requires more subtlety.  The reason your approach could even be adjusted/weighted at all was because it so happened that the criterion for $B$ to reroll is such that the probability of a reroll is equal to the probability of no reroll.  So we give an example where this is not the case by modifying the criterion.

Suppose $B$ decides instead to reroll if the first roll is less than or equal to $7$.  Then in the case where there is no reroll, there are $13(12)/2 = 78$ desired outcomes where $A$ outrolls $B$, out of a possible $13(20) = 260$ outcomes.  If there is a reroll, then as before, there are $190$ desired outcomes where $A$ outrolls $B$ out of a possible $20(20) = 400$ outcomes. But because the probability of reroll is $7/20$ and no longer the same as the probability of no reroll which is $13/20$, the probability of no reroll given $A$ outrolled $B$ is now $$\frac{\frac{78}{260} \frac{13}{20}}{\frac{78}{260} \frac{13}{20} + \frac{190}{400} \frac{7}{20}} = \frac{156}{289}.$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the weighting formula you used. Is there a formal name for this or a reference where I can read up on it? It looks like it's definition of conditional probability under the hood?

Comment: @Iamanon Don't get hung up on names or references.  Use your own reasoning.  If I say in "Scenario 1" that there are $10$ desired outcomes out of $20$ equally probable outcomes, and in "Scenario 2" there are $40$ desired outcomes out of $50$ equally probable outcomes, surely you would not be so naive as to calculate the overall probability of a desired outcome as $\frac{10}{10+ 40} = 0.2$ when in each scenario, the chance of the desired outcome is at least $1/2$?

Comment: Yeah I understand this example you gave in the comment, but what I don't understand is how you determined what the weights should be.

Comment: @Iamanon The example is virtually identical to your actual problem. Scenario 1 = NR, with $45$ desired outcomes out of a possible $200$.  Scenario 2 = RR, with $190$ desired outcomes out of a possible $400$.  In all scenarios, there are always $20$ possible outcomes for $A$.  In Scenario 1 = NR, there are only $10$ possible outcomes for $B$, for a total of $200$ possible outcomes.  In Scenario 2 = RR, there are $20$ possible outcomes for $B$, for a total of $400$.  The fact that $\Pr[RR] = \Pr[NR] = 1/2$ means that both scenarios are equally likely, thus cancel out.

Comment: To be clear, the "weights" I speak of are not weights on the scenarios.  The weighting is on the desired outcomes.  The number of desired outcomes cannot be added up like $10 + 40$ or $45 + 190$ because doing so ignores the probabilities of those outcomes based on the total possible.  A probability is in essence a *weighted* count of desired outcomes, where the weight is the total number of outcomes.

Comment: Therefore, if we had a situation where Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 are not equally likely to occur, there is an additional set of weights in the calculation, as Bayes' theorem requires.  But since in your case it is equally likely, these weights cancel out of the numerator and denominator as you saw in my method of solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, but I am not sure, that the problem concerns the following game:

"$A,B$ are tossing a fair $20$ sided die.  $A$ takes whatever value comes up but $B$ must toss again if the first value was $≤10$ at which point only the second value $B$ gets counts.  Given that $A$ got a higher roll than $B$, what is the conditional probability that $B$ did not roll twice?"

If so, this is a routine application of Bayes' Theorem.

Note that if $B$ gets $>10$ on the first roll then the probability that $A$ wins is given by $$\frac 1{10}\times \frac 9{20}+\frac 1{10}\times \frac 8{20}+\cdots +\frac 1{10}\times  \frac 0{20}$$  which sums to $\frac 9{40}$.

If $≤10$ then $B$ rolls again and, of course, this is then just a fair match between $A,B$, since the initial toss does not signify.  In that case, the probability that $A$ wins is $\frac 12\times \left(1-\frac 1{20}\right)=\frac {19}{40}$

Thus the probability that $A$ wins this unfair game is $$\frac 12\times \frac 9{40}+\frac 12\times \frac {19}{40}$$

Of that, the portion explained by $B$ only rolling once is $\frac 12\times \frac 9{40}$ so Bayes' tells us that the desired answer is $$\frac 12\times \frac 9{40}\Bigg/ \left(\frac 12\times \frac 9{40}+\frac 12\times \frac {19}{40}\right)=\frac 9{28}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to think about, assume that $A$ doesn’t roll until you have either re-rolled or decided not to do so. There are $10$ equally likely outcomes of the first roll in which you do not re-roll, so there are $200$ equally likely outcomes in which you do not re-roll and $A$ wins in $45$ of them.

There are also $10$ equally likely outcomes of the first roll in which you **do** re-roll, and for each of them there are $400$ equally likely final outcomes, in $190$ of which $A$ wins. If you were really counting outcomes, that would be $1900$ wins for $A$ in $4000$ possible outcomes. However, since the result of the first roll doesn’t affect the result of the game, it does no harm to think of this as $190$ wins for $A$ in $400$ possible equally likely outcomes.

But you still have different numbers of outcomes making up the $NR$ and $RR$ events: the former is divided into $200$ equally likely outcomes and the latter into $400$. Thus, since the $NR$ and $RR$ events **are** equally likely, each of the $200$ outcomes that you’re considering in the $NR$ case is twice as likely as each of the outcomes that you’re considering in the $RR$, and the calculation therefore cannot be a simple matter of counting total outcomes. In order to do that, you have to put them on the same basis, e.g., by noting that $190$ wins for $A$ out of $400$ outcomes is the same ratio as $95$ wins out of $200$ outcomes. Then you can calculate the desired probability as

$$\frac{45}{45+95}=\frac{45}{140}=\frac9{28}\,.$$

In effect this is halving the weight of each outcome in the $RR$ case.
Alternatively, you could double the weight of each outcome in the $NR$ case and compute

$$\frac{90}{90+190}=\frac{90}{280}=\frac9{28}\,.$$